# How can I import .eps in Mathematica without losing the text?

Tags: import, wolfram-mathematica, stata, eps

I am trying to import a histogram produced by Stata as an .eps file into *Mathematica*, but it does not display axes' labels. That is, for some reason, *Mathematica* does not import .eps as but rather transforms it.

How can I avoid that? As of now, I am using plain

```
Import["~/hst.eps"]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert .eps file to .pdf in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647607/how-can-i-convert-eps-file-to-pdf-in-mathematica)

Comment: @Nick I think these questions have different scope although the question you linked is formulated very similar to this question. I think we should separate these questions: this is about importing .eps in *Mathematica*, [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18647607/590388) question is about converting .eps to .pdf in *Mathematica*. I will edit them appropriately.

Comment: That's helpful. The original problem was the posting of two closely related questions, but if you can pull them apart, that's good.

Comment: You might consider flagging your question for migration to [Mathematica.SE].

Comment: upload a simple test EPS file to a suitable web site and it will be easier to find out what's going wrong

Comment: sure, this is the sample file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/824842/orders_weekly.eps

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129309/pdf-figure-missing-text-elements-in-beamer-presentation) with LateX and a pdf graph recently, which also manifested itself with the eps version. I wound up modifying the user-written graphexportpdf and things seemed to work out. Perhaps you will find this solution helpful.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* currently (v.9) usually cannot import textual elements from .eps files properly. One possible solution would be to export your plot as .pdf rather than .eps from you plotting software and then `Import` generated .pdf. If you need to import the text as text you can turn off outlining by using the `"TextOutlines" -> False` option.

If exporting to .pdf from your plotting software  is not possible you can [convert .eps to .pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18651814/590388) by another program and then `Import` generated .pdf as above.
For your file [orders_weekly.eps](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/824842/orders_weekly.eps) using the [`gsEPS2PDFEmbedFonts` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18651814/590388) and then `Import`ing generated .pdf, I get (*Mathematica* 8.0.4):

```
gsEPS2PDFEmbedFonts["orders_weekly.eps", "orders_weekly.pdf"]
graphics=First@Import["orders_weekly.pdf"(*,"TextOutlines"->False*)];
Show[graphics, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

I have commented the `"TextOutlines" -> False` option because *Mathematica* 8.0.4 still imports rotated text incorrectly with it. I haven't tested it with v.9 though.

---

Another possibility is to convert all the glypth in the .eps file to oultines. Based on [Jens Nöckel's code](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Mathematica2Illustrator),

```
gsEPS2outlinedEPS[epsPath_String, outlinedEPSPath_String] := 
 Run["gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=epswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=\"" <> 
   outlinedEPSPath <> "\" -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE \"" <> epsPath <> 
   "\" -c quit"]
```

Here `gswin64c.exe` is the name of GhostScript executable for 64bit Windows systems, for Linux replace it with `gs`.
Note that you should have [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) installed and configured (for Windows you [should](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.10/Use.htm#MS_Windows) add `gs\bin` and `gs\lib` to the `PATH`, where `gs` is the top-level Ghostscript directory)

Comment: can I somehow automate the process?