# How can I convert .eps file to .pdf in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, ghostscript

How can I convert .eps to .pdf inside *Mathematica* (perhaps using GhostScript?)?

Answer (score 2):

After installing [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and setting appropriate environment variables (for Windows you [should](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.10/Use.htm#MS_Windows) add `gs\bin` and `gs\lib` to the `PATH`, where `gs` is the top-level Ghostscript directory) you can use [Jens Nöckel's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9047/280) for converting .eps to .pdf (all the glyphs will be outlined):

```
gsEPS2PDF[epsPath_String, pdfPath_String] := 
 Run["gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=\"" <> 
   pdfPath <> "\" -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE \"" <> epsPath <> "\" -c quit"]
```

Here `gswin64c.exe` is the name of GhostScript executable for 64bit Windows systems, for Linux replace it with `gs`.

Another method based on  [Kurt Pfeifle' code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234150/590388) (without font outlining):

```
gsEPS2PDFEmbedFonts[epsPath_String, pdfOutputPath_String] := 
 Run["gswin64c.exe -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts -o \"" <> 
   pdfOutputPath <> 
   "\" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \"" <> epsPath <> 
   "\""]
```

Here `c:/windows/fonts` is the directory where fonts are located. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3461186/590388) for information about GhostScript command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
gr = Import["file.eps", "eps"]
Export["file.pdf", gr, "pdf"]
```

Comment: In most cases `Import`ing of .eps files returns `$Failed` as for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647024/how-can-i-import-eps-in-mathematica-without-losing-the-text?lq=1#comment27602188_18647024) file.